# Etherscan Address Withdrawl question

Tags: etherscan

I participated in two ICOs. It asked for an Ethereum address, I gave it the address of my Binance Acct.  The Binance account did not save the tokens or the ERC20 deposits.  However, when I go to Etherscan, it shows the value, the deposits, and tokens, almost $600.

Is there anyway to transfer or recover these?

Comment: Since you gave them Binance's address, Binance now has the tokens. You'll have to ask them if they're willing to send them to you. (You'll need an actual address of your own to receive them.)

Comment: @smarx can you convert your comment into an answer, so he can accept your answer, and this question isn't left "unanswered"?

Comment: I think the question should be closed instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your tokens are not recoverable. As per [Binance](https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003875072-Statement-on-ICO-or-Token-Sale-Contribution-from-your-Binance-Account):

> We would like to remind all of you to not contribute to ICO or Token
>   Sale addresses directly from your Binance account. Please first
>   withdraw your coins/tokens to a personal wallet address and contribute
>   from there. Binance will not be able to recover the funds/tokens
>   related to your contribution.
>
> Thanks for your support!
>
> Binance Team
>
> 2018/01/09

As a rule, never send ETH to an ICO from any exchange, only from your ERC20 wallet.